# Workaround Duplicate Label

Tags: custom-fields, civicase, activities

I noticed that all labels in the "Activity Type Options" and "Custom Fields" cannot be the same. For example, if I wanted to add a "Medical Assessment" activity type, I cannot use the same label again. This matters, because when I assign this activity type to a specific case, I have custom fields attached to this medical assessment activity.

The problem is, when I create another case type and use "medical assessment" again, I want different custom fields to be attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't too many options here. At this time, labels have to be unique. We can't put "Medical Assessment" in case type Family Model and "Medical Assessment" in case type Youth Model, for example.

The workaround I used was to label all the Activity Types by ordering. For example in Family Model, it would be "1. Medical Assessment" and in case type Youth Model, it would be "2. Medical Assessment". All activity types on the case dropdown list needs to be numbered too. There are unique custom fields attached to these activity types.

FAMILY MODEL
1. Medical Assessment
1. Mental Health Assessment

YOUTH MODEL
1. Mental Health Assessment
2. Medical Assessment

Answer (score 0):

You could rename the activities - for example: "Medical Assessment - Type 1", "Medical Assessment - Type 2" or something more descriptive and link the appropriate custom fields to each one.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work very well because they are different case types. Therefore, you would be putting "Assessment Type 2" in a whole another case timeline.